# REST: Correct URI-Syntax for a collection of resources

Tags: rest, collections, uri

In an RESTful application, I have these URIs as an example:

```
1: /users
2: /users/{id}
3: /users/{id}/messages
4: /users/{id}/messages/{message}
```

While the syntax of URIs 2 and 4 is right, a single resource (like a file) is accessible with these URIs, I'm not sure about 1 and 3.

Should an URI, under which a collection of resources is available (comparable to a directory with files), have a ending slash "/"?

```
1: `/users/` instead of `/users`?
3: `/users/{id}/messages/` instead of `/users/{id}/messages`?
```

Why I'm thinking about this:

When a normal file system is accessible via a web-server, directory paths need an ending slash and usually a web-server will add these when missing, and the server will reply with an http-code 302 and the correct location with the ending "/".

When I tried to add relative xlink-anchors in my XML-code which is sent as the response, I needed to add the upper resource to this link (f.e. `messages/3`instead of `3` or `./3` to link to `/users/5/messages/3`)

What is your view on this?